# Creating a table in an excel sheet using Pandas and XLSXWriter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

So I am using Pandas and Python to transfer all the data from one excel sheet to a completely new sheet, everyday the data gets updated and hence the new Excel sheet being used gets overridden with updated data. I've been trying in the new sheet to have all the data that is overridden put into a table format within the new Excel.
When I run the code I have made for the table it overrides the data but doesn't put it into a table format?
The following code is what I have so far for the table formatting:

````
import xlsxwriter 

excel_file_1 = 'Incident Report.xls'
df_first_shift = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\M\Downloads\Incident Report.xls')
print(df_first_shift)
df_all = pd.concat([df_first_shift])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Incident_Report.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [df_all.to_excel(r'C:\Users\M\OneDrive\Test\Incident_Report.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')]})

dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

(max_row, max_col) = dataframe.shape
column_settings = [{'header':column} for column in dataframe.columns]

worksheet.add_table(0,0, max_row, max_col - 1, {'columns' : column_settings})
worksheet.set_column(0, max_col - 1, 12)

writer.save()```
````

Comment: You can't use XlsxWriter to update a file. It can only be used to create a new file. You will need to use OpenPyXL as the engine instead. The process of adding a table will be different in that case.